# Can Repetitive Database Access Code be Streamlined using Callbacks in C#?

Tags: c#, webapi

Within this class, I've incorporated methods to retrieve data by ID and to create new data.

Each of these methods entails a boilerplate code segment, as depicted below:

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
```

Is there a strategy to streamline this boilerplate code, perhaps by utilizing callbacks? If that's the case, how can it be achieved?

```
public class SqlDataAccess
    {
        public List<BookModel> LoadData(string sqlQuery, string connectionString)
        {
            List<BookModel> books = new List<BookModel>();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    BookModel book = ExtractBookFromReader(reader);
                    books.Add(book);
                }
                reader.Close();

                return books;
            }
        }

        public List<BookModel> LoadDataById(int id, string sqlQuery, string connectionString)
        {
            List<BookModel> books = new List<BookModel>();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    BookModel book = ExtractBookFromReader(reader);
                    books.Add(book);
                }
                reader.Close();

                return books;
            }
        }

        public List<BookModel> PostNewBook(BookModel newBook, string sqlQuery, string connectionString)
        {
            List<BookModel> books = new List<BookModel>();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", newBook.Title);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", newBook.Author);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", newBook.Description);
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    BookModel book = ExtractBookFromReader(reader);
                    books.Add(book);
                }
                reader.Close();

                return books;
            }
        }

        private BookModel ExtractBookFromReader(SqlDataReader reader)
        {
            BookModel book = new BookModel();
            book.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]);
            book.Title = Convert.ToString(reader["title"]);
            book.Author = Convert.ToString(reader["author"]);
            book.Description = Convert.ToString(reader["description"]);
            return book;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are asking this question, then you should look at what an ORM could do for you. For example [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can usually use delegates to replace the "meat" of the function where there is substantial initialization code, for example something like:

```
public List<T> Load( string connectionString, Func<SqlDataReader, T> readerToObject, string sqlQuery, params object[] parameters)
    {
        using var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();
        using var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        using var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        return readerToObject(reader);
        
    }
```

But that does not mean it is the best approach. The common approach to read data from databases is to use an ORM, like [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/), that lets you use linq to query the database. There can also be readability issues with using callbacks/delegates, since there is no single place you can check to understand what a method does.

But the general approach is at least worth knowing about.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic repository pattern with ADO, but in my opinion it's too much work, when ORM's can do the work for you. For instance in [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper), your data access class could look like this;

```cs
public class SqlDataAccess
{
    public List<BookModel> LoadData(string sqlQuery, string connectionString)
    {
        List<BookModel> books = new List<BookModel>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            return conn.Query<BookModel>(sqlQuery).ToList();
        }
    }

    public BookModel LoadDataById(int id, string sqlQuery, string connectionString)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            return conn.QuerySingle<BookModel>(sqlQuery, new {id});
        }
    }

    public bool PostNewBook(BookModel newBook, string sqlQuery, string connectionString)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            return conn.ExecuteScalar<int>(sqlQuery,
                new 
                {
                    title = newBook.Title,
                    author = newBook.Author,
                    description = newBook.Description
                }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure) == 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that your database fields are easily mappable to your business objects, otherwise you will have to write a custom mapper. It also assumes your stored procedure for inserting returns the number of changed records.
As you see mapping is automatic and SqlDataReader is done away with using extension methods on the connection.